# How to create a sub-bullet point in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, html

To illustrate sub-bullet points in Markdown:

- Stack Exchange

  - Super User
  - Ask Ubuntu
  - Server Fault

Comment: Are you composing the e-mail in `HTML` format, or plain-text?

Comment: @spikey_richie HTML, edited tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have "Compose messages in HTML format" enabled (checkmarked) for the account you are sending from in Tools > Account Settings > Composition & Addressing, you should see a style toolbar like below (where Indent text is an icon that is the 3rd to the right of the bullet icon):

[image: Thunderbird Indent text example]

So you should get the indent with bullets you are looking for by selecting the lines that you want indented, then clicking on the Indent text icon.

From there, if you want the sub-bullet points to be black filled disks instead of Thunderbird's outlined disks (default), then you would select all the bulleted text (being careful to drag from above to below so you grab both levels of UL), select Insert > HTML and ad `style="list-style: disc;"` into the child UL, like so:

[image: Change the bullet style in HTML example]

Alternatively, you could also just copy what you have in your original post above (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on a PC) and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) into the email. That would give you the sub-bullet point formatting and bullet style as well.

Comment: Yes, pasting from the web works as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eHkY.png

Comment: You might want to use the lossless PNG format in the future for basic screenshots, the JPG compression can damage readability.